# System.AccessViolationException at cout << line

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2013, header-files, access-violation

So i got this `Exception` and i know it's just because I'm new to C++ and my code is wrong(So, no, it's not an already asked question).

I got `Frog.cpp` file and `program.cpp` file.

Frog.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Frog.h"

using namespace std;

Frog::Frog()
{
    (*this).status = Free;
    (*this).color = "Green";
    (*this).weight = 200; // In grams
}
Frog::Frog(float weight, int age, char* color, char* nickname, Status status)
{
    (*this).weight = weight;
    (*this).age = age;
    (*this).color = color;
    (*this).nickname = nickname;
    (*this).status = status;
}
Frog::Frog(float weight, int age)
{
    (*this).weight = weight;
    (*this).age = age;
}
void Frog::currentState()
{
    cout << "Weight:" << (*this).weight << " ,Age:" << (*this).age << " ,Color:" << (*this).color << " , Nickname:" << (*this).nickname << " , Status:" << (*this).status << endl; // The ling that causeing the mayhem
}
```

Frog.h:

```
#ifndef FROG_H
#define FROG_H
typedef enum Status { Free, Urban, Plate, Dead };

class Frog
{
    private:
        float weight;
        int age;
        char* color;
        char* nickname;
        Status status;
    public:
        Frog();
        Frog(float weight, int age, char* color, char* nickname, Status status);
        Frog(float weight, int age);
        void currentState();
};

#endif
```

Program.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Frog.h"

using namespace std;

void main()
{  
    Frog frog = Frog();

    frog.currentState(); // I get the Exception on this line


    getch();
}
```

The Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
       at std.char_traits<char>.length(SByte* _First) in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iosfwd:line 523
       at std.operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(basic_ostream<char\,std::char_traits<char> >* _Ostr, SByte* _Val) in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\ostream:line 791
       at Frog.currentState(Frog* )
```

The bad line is `cout << "Weight:" << (*this).weight << " ,Age:" << (*this).age << " ,Color:" << (*this).color << " , Nickname:" << (*this).nickname << " , Status:" << (*this).status << endl;` at `Frog.cpp`.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: OT: You can write `foo->bla` instead of `(*foo).bla` for any pointer `foo`. (And also a few non-pointers.)

Comment: you're not checking that the nickname is valid, and you don't set it to a default value in the default constructor. Trying to print a const char* that's not pointing to a valid c string is a vary bad plan.

Comment: Side Note: Please use class initializer lists (and replace (*this) by this->)

Comment: @BaummitAugen An object in C++ is a pointer?

Comment: @God `this` is a pointer.

Comment: A frog of 200 g? Where did you find those?

Comment: @God Use `std::string` rather than `char*`.

Comment: To add, there is also an undefined behavior assigning a 'char' to a static string... Haha ...200g Frog @SergeyA

Comment: `System.AccessViolationException` sounds like C++/clr

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, but how's that relevant for the given example code?

Comment: @SergeyA [Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath_frog).

Comment: @BaummitAugen, oh my. Scary stuff.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not much, native C++ just ends in a crash (if the programmer is lucky)

Comment: ·@πάνταῥεῖ I may be wrong, but a ref-class pointer (if not explicitly initialized) is initialized to zero, always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Frog frog = Frog();` creates a default constructed `Frog`.  Your default constructor is

```
Frog::Frog()
{
    (*this).status = Free;
    (*this).color = "Green";
    (*this).weight = 200; // In grams
}
```

Which does not initialize `nickname`.  When you go to print it in `currentState()` you are accessing garbage pointers.  This is undefined behavior and is causing the access violation.

I suggest you use a `std::string` so you do not have to worry about this.  I also suggest you use [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).  With that you class would look like

```
class Frog
{
    private:
        float weight;
        int age;
        std::string color;
        std::string nickname;
        Status status;
    public:
        Frog() : status(Free), color("Green"), weight(200), age(0), nickname("") {}
        Frog(float weight, int age, std::string color, std::string nickname, Status status) : 
            status(status), color(color), weight(weight), age(age), nickname(nickname) {}
        Frog(float weight, int age);
        void currentState();
};
```

Comment: Whats member initialization list?

Comment: @God the [c++ Super-FAQ has several entries on the subject](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists)

Comment: @God I added a link into the answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok , i used the member initialization list and i get `Error function 'Frog::Frog(void)' already has a body`

Comment: @God More than likely it is to do with you having the constructor in the header and cpp files.  If you see in my example I have them just in the header file.  You no longer need them in the cpp file.

Comment: @NathanOliver Never mind. i get it now. just deleted the other constructor. Thanks man.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I'm just stupid.

as @jaggedSpire suggested:

I didn't initialized the `nickname` and the `age` properties.

Although i though that in `C++` the properties get a default value if i use a default constructor.

Thanks guys.

Comment: They *do* get a default value if not explicitly initialized. You're just using c-strings, so the default value is an invalid argument to pass to `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`. NathanOliver is giving good advice: use `std::string` and initializer lists

Comment: Not the downvoter, but think on this: What would be the default value for a pointer and of what use would it be to you since it likely won't point anywhere you could safely print?